# How to solve this error ":(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN10Management11OpenEm'"

Tags: c++, c, linker, cygwin, wrapper

I need to call some methods from a C++ program in a C program.

But I just have one shared library (`.dll`) to use those methods.

To make it, first a create a wrapper in C to call the methods from the `dll` to be used in the C program. I have attention and I make sure that I declare the functions with `extern "C"` to avoid name mangling.

But when a compile I have a set of errors (shown in down) when a linking wall the `.o`'s:

```
g++ -o bonnie++ bonnie++.o bon_io.o bon_file.o bon_time.o semaphore.o sync.o thread.o bon_suid.o duration.o rand.o util.o utils.o super.o pcm_file.o inode.o iname.o dir.o pcm.o -lpthread -L./ -lSmart
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN10Management11OpenEm'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN10Management12CloseEm'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x73): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN10Management17EnumerateEv'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN18DemonstratorDevC1Ev'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0xf7): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN18DemonstratorDevD1Ev'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x121): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN18DemonstratorDevice11OpenEi'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x138): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN18DemonstratorDev12CloseAdapterEv'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x15f): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN18DemonstratorDev23ConfigureClockFrequencyEi15_ClockFrequency'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN18DemonstratorDev21AdaptationBlockEnableEv'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x1a1): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN18CommandsManagementC1ER18DemonstratorDev'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x1df): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN18CommandsManagementD1Ev'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x21a): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN18CommandsManagement20DeviceInitializationEim9TimerCtrl'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x253): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN18CommandsManagement24EnableEmbeddedOperationsER8OWStatusim9TimerCtrl'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x290): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN18CommandsManagement12RegionUnlockEmmim9TimerCtrl'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x2da): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN18CommandsManagement17BufferedOverwriteEmmPKhiiim9TimerCtrl'
pcm.o:pcm.c:(.text+0x32c): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN18CommandsManagement9BurstReadEmPtmih9BurstTypeim9TimerCtrl'
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.7.3/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: pcm.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame$_ZN10ManagementC1Ev'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:37: recipe for target `bonnie++' failed
make: *** [bonnie++] Error 1
```

Someone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In what object file is `Management` defined?

Comment: `Management` (and `DemonstratorDev`, `CommandsManagement` ) are defined in a shared library (`Smart.dll`).
I link all the objects file with the shared library with `-L./ -lSmart`. I am doing the linking correctly? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you include the extern "C" function declaration header files in your wrapper method source file?  if not, this error will occur

Comment: Yes, I am including the header files in my wrapper(pcm.c).I really do not understand why these errors are occurring...

Comment: One more thing, all the `undefined references` are defined in the shared library (`dll`). The problem may be happening because I'm doing wrong linking between a `pcm.o` and `smart.dll` ?

Comment: got it. you should add **pcm_share_library_adapter.cc** and **pcm_share_library_adapter.h**, then you add `extern "C" someApiMethodAdapter(parameter);` in **pcm_share_library_adapter.cc** and add `someApiMethodAdapter(parameter){ return someApiMethod(parameter);}` in **pcm_share_library_adapter.cc** all your code should call 'someApiMethodAdapter not directly call sharelibary method directly